# Using a Script to control Audio driver functions

Tags: windows-8, audio, drivers

I have Asus Essence STX sound card.

When I want to change the sound card's output device (eg: from Speakers to Headphones) I have to launch the driver GUI and change it there.

However, I would much rather be able to control this function using a macro on my keyboard or mouse.

Is it possible to write a script to do this? I imagine I could launch a .bat script from my mouse or keyboard and would be more convenient.

Comment: What OS is this for?

Comment: Windows / Windows 8

Answer (score 3):

There is a small utility application, written by EreTIk called [DefSound](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://eretik.omegahg.com/tools/DefSound.html) (Translated Page) that lets you create a shortcut to activate a windows sound render device.

To get this up and running, first you need to do a couple of things:

1. Download the DefSound Binary or the Source Code from EreTIks website
2. Extract and, if using the source code, build the executable
3. Determine the **index** of the *sound render device* you want to enable
4. Ensure all available playback devices are enabled and connected
5. Create a shortcut to set the default device

Let me explain something I found about the *sound render device*:

- It refers to one of the Playback Devices you would normally set manually (ie: Headphones, Speakers, etc)
- The **index** is *not* determined by it's position in the Playback Devices list

Therefore, to acquire the correct **index** some experimentation will need to be performed:

1. Open the folder containing the files you extracted and/or built earlier
2. Create a shortcut to DefSound.exe by first highlighting DefSound.exe then right-clicking and selecting 'Create Shortcut'
3. You should have a file called 'DefSound.exe - Shortcut' which you should rename to something that you want to keep, for this one I called it 'Headphones' - we will create the others later
4. Right-click the Headphones shortcut and select 'Properties'
5. Edit the target to select a different device (see below)

To see how the utility can be used to set the default device, let us look at the usage:

```
Usage: DefSound.exe
Run and show system tray icon

Or: DefSound.exe <NUMBER> [STRING]
Change default sound render device and exit.
The device sets zero-based index (NUMBER)
STRING is a role, may be:
  ALL    - all roles (default string value)
  CON    - console(system notification sounds and voice commands)
  MMEDIA - multimedia (music, movies, etc...)
  VOICE  - voice communications

For example DefSound.exe 0
Select device with index 0 (first device) as default, all roles
```

Therefore, by changing the usage, or *target* - we can set the default device, here goes

1. At the end of the target field, add a '0' then press OK
2. Did the playback device change to headphones?

   - Yes: Repeat the above steps for every device you want to create a shortcut to
   - No: Increase the value we wrote in the end of the target field

By this stage you should have a couple of shortcuts to the devices you want to enable, from there it is a matter of assigning hotkeys to enable them on-the-fly, or as I did: place them at the top of my startmenu.

Cheers

Comment: This is actually pretty interesting, I have gotten this to work, unfortunately it does not exactly do what I need it to do. This changes the windows default audio output device. However, my sound card only registers as a single audio device, and I choose the specific output from the sound card's utility program. (the sound card has several outputs)